# Spring Boot POST request doesn't work

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to build Spring boot REST application with angularJS.

So, application is loading well, every JS and CSS files included. The problem is that when I am doing GET request, it goes right way, but when I am doing POST request it fails and doesn't try to call the controller method.

That's my Spring Boot Application class

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"org.test.controllers", "org.test.services"})
@Import({ WebSecurityConfig.class, DBConfig.class, ViewConfig.class})
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("STARTING APP");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And that's my controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tag")
public class TagController {
    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Iterable<Tag> getAllTags() {
        return tagService.getAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Tag saveTag(@RequestBody Tag tag) {
        return tagService.save(tag);
    }
}
```

So, when I am doing `$http.get("/tag", success, error)` it gives `[]`, which means that controller was called.

And when I am doing `$http.post("/tag", {name: 'name'}, success, error)` it returns `{"timestamp":1489939480282,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/tag"}`

To make sure that mapping was done, here's part of logs

```
Mapped "{[/tag],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.test.model.Tag org.expotest.controllers.TagController.saveTag(org.test.model.Tag)
```

I am running on Tomcat server if it matters.

Any ideas what could be wrong in my configuration? That seems really strange for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to make POST through some REST client?

Comment: Could you please post your model Tag class.....did you tested the same payload with postman ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring security try disabling csrf in your configure method, should look something like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
}
```